# Random Border-Color CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, colors

I have 5 list items on my page, with the following CSS applied to them:

```css
#content .gallery_work ul li {
    background-color: #FEF5D6 !important;
    border-right: 15px solid blue;
    color: #373C46;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 250px !important;
    margin: 10px !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 225px !important;
}
```

what I'd like to have is 5 possible border colors, and for each li to get one of the colors randomly applied to it.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Please specify if you are willing to use an SSSL or JavaScript

Comment: Randomly chosen once or per request?

Comment: not possible with plain HTML/CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242999/random-color-border-javascript-around-database-entries-thumbnails

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just generate a number in JavaScript or your server side language of choice.

You could do it in JavaScript...

```
var color = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
```

...or PHP...

```
$color = "#" . dechex(rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
```

Your comment...

> Instead of using completely random colors, is there a way I could declare a number and then have it randomly choose from them?

Yes, for example...

```
$colors = array("#000", "#fff");

$randomColor = $colors[array_rand($colors)];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wants to use JS (or server side), but the solution is very elegant.. +1

Comment: My site uses PHP so could use the second option. Instead of using completely random colors, is there a way I could declare a number and then have it randomly choose from them?

Comment: @DaveHunter Yes, set up an array of colours, and use `array_rand()` to choose a random key.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Would you suggest something other than JS or a server-side language?

Comment: Please could you provide a little more detail on using this - I am a relative beginner with anything over simple CSS

Comment: So with the updated PHP you've added, where do I put this on my page (i.e. header, body etc.) and do i need any more info to make it happen on page load? Finally, how do I limit it to a div or element with a particular class?

Comment: @DaveHunter If you're asking that, you're probably better reading a few PHP tutorials first.

Comment: If anyone is willing to provide some advice, it'd be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A solution that covers all edge cases, as in add proper zero padding:

```
function randomColor() {
    return (function(h) {
         return '#000000'.substr(0, 7 - h.length) + h;
    })((~~(Math.random() * (1 << 24))).toString(16));
}
```

Originally by Remy Sharp: http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/#comment-34878